# Child controller not inheriting from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've been having a lot of trouble with understanding scope inheritance and I've tried my best to pass data objects from a parent controller into the child controller, but I can't seem to get things to work. Can someone explain why this isn't functioning? Thank you!

**EDIT**: I didn't specify this earlier, but it's a project requirement to use the John Papa style guide, so I can't solve this problem by using `$scope` in either of the controllers.

**UPDATE**: It seems I misunderstood the purpose of using `this`... based on help from posters below, I now understand that certain actions require the use of `$scope` and John Papa's style guide simply asks developers to use `this` when appropriate to avoid scope conflicts, not as a *replacement* for scope

**JS**

```
//parent.controller.js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ParentController', ParentController);

    ParentController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function ParentController($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log(this);
        vm.test = {};
        vm.test.label = "This is being set in the parent controller.";
    }
})();

//child.controller.js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ChildController', ChildController);

    ChildController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function ChildController($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.test = vm.test;
    }
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController as vm">
     <div>PARENT: {{vm.test.label}}</div>
     <div ng-controller="ChildController as vm">
          <div>CHILD: {{vm.test.label}}</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT**

```
PARENT: 'This is being set in the parent controller.'
CHILD:
```

Comment: You should have only one module, why you are declaring two modules?

Comment: Check this plunkr, https://plnkr.co/edit/bs9Zaba0yW8lqlStoe7Z?p=preview

Comment: @Aparna thank you very much for the help. That plunkr works, but it's [against John Papa style to use $scope](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) and it's a project requirement to abide by that style guide. Just updated my post with that info since I didn't specify earlier.

Comment: Oh and @Aparna, I'm not declaring two modules, just getting two references to the app since in my code, those controllers are in two separate files. Again, sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: @Aparna just revised your plunkr to better demonstrate what I'm struggling with, [check it out](https://plnkr.co/edit/dOCpXXq1c5wxiJ2xZyYT?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is: vm is also the part of the $scope itself. So you can not have same this instance for Parent & Child controller. Otherwise you will be facing issues while using them.
If you want to isolate this instance for Parent & Child then give different names.
Since vm is also the part of the controller so if you want to access Parent's vm inside Child controller then you will have to do `$scope.vm`

Working code as per your requirement is attached below:

```
Controller
---------
(function () {
                'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('ParentController', ParentController);

    ParentController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function ParentController($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        console.log(this);
        vm.test = {};
        vm.test.label = "This is being set in the parent controller.";
    }
})();

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ChildController', ChildController);

    ChildController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function ChildController($scope) {
        var childVm = this;
        childVm.test = $scope.vm.test;
    }
})();


HTML
---

<div ng-app="app">
            <div ng-controller="ParentController as vm">
                <div>PARENT: {{vm.test.label}}</div>
                <div ng-controller="ChildController as childVm">
                    <div>CHILD: {{childVm.test.label}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I really appreciate the help. So I guess I just don't have a great understanding of `var vm = this;` and how that compares to `$scope`... I just updated my post to specify that I need to abide by the John Papa style guide, and it's against that guide to use `$scope` in that manner. What can I do to get around using `$scope.vm` in my child controller? Thanks again!

Comment: Just revised [a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/dOCpXXq1c5wxiJ2xZyYT?p=preview) from a commenter above, hopefully this will better demonstrate my confusion:

Comment: It seems you misunderstood what John Papa trying to say. He says if you have Parent & Child controller relationship then instead of directly using $scope, we should be using "controller as" syntax. Through this we can isolate Parent & Child properties and avoid conflicts. Continued...

Comment: But if you have to access Parent properties into Child then you will have to take the help of $scope in this manner: $scope.vm

Answer (score 1):

After checking the plnkr,hope I was able to understand your question, and giving answer based on it:

In controller file, for ChildController

```
var childCtrl = this;

// Why don't either of these work?
// childCtrl.test = parentCtrl.test;
// childCtrl.test = this.parentCtrl.test;
```

- assigning parentCtrl.test, doesn't makes any sense, as it is the object of the parent controller.
- this.parentCtrl.test will get evaluated to childCtrl.parentCtrl.test which is invalid.

Following worked because-

```
// But this does...
childCtrl.test = $scope.parentCtrl.test;
```

During the code execution

- Two separate scopes will get created each for ParentController and ChildController.
- child will inherit the properties of parent, those which are not present in childController and will be assigned to the childController scope.
  Due to which you where able to access value in child with scope.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight, everything you said is inline with the poster I was discussing this with on Saturday. I appreciate your help and time!